# Artifactory : java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Unable to deploy artfacts on our artifactory set on https.

Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
>     Failed to persist file with sha1: ed7a19cc58e736b5cd9d1ef5ec7d2ff897d4793f Status code: 404

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
  Failed to persist file with sha1: ed7a19cc58e736b5cd9d1ef5ec7d2ff897d4793f Status code: 404
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.prepareAndDeploy(DeployTask.java:101)
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.collectProjectBuildInfo(DeployTask.java:59)
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.taskAction(DeployTask.java:53)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
      ... 30 more
  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
  Failed to persist file with sha1: ed7a19cc58e736b5cd9d1ef5ec7d2ff897d4793f Status code: 404
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.prepareAndDeploy(DeployTask.java:99)
      ... 46 more
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
  Failed to persist file with sha1: ed7a19cc58e736b5cd9d1ef5ec7d2ff897d4793f Status code: 404
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.deployArtifacts(DeployTask.java:210)
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.lambda$null$1(DeployTask.java:97)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
  Failed to persist file with sha1: ed7a19cc58e736b5cd9d1ef5ec7d2ff897d4793f Status code: 404
      at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:697)
      at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:379)
      at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
      at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:352)
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.deployArtifacts(DeployTask.java:295)
      at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.deployArtifacts(DeployTask.java:197)
      ... 1 more

Comment: You probably need to check the server side logs. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Log+Files

Comment: unable to access the logs