# Artifactory: Failed to persist file; Status code: 404 / Gradle

Tags: gradle, bitbucket, artifactory, bitbucket-pipelines, jfrog-cli

we facing the same issue as described in [Artifactory : java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745503/artifactory-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-deploy-file-status-code-404-respo) when running our deployment via bitbucket pipelines.

This happens on Artifactory cloud to all pipelines from on day to another.

```
 Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
  Failed to persist file with sha1: 0fexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Status code: 404
```

In Artifactory system-logs I get following warning all the time, but I'm not sure if this issue is connected. Beside following message there are no errors in logs:

```
2020-08-25T16:26:43.889Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [c19ba246224f712c] [ntuallyPersistedAddFileTask:96] [al-binary-provider-2] - Failed to delete 'add file' after completing eventually persisted task '/storage/eventual/_add/a3/a396fb897aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

ERROR in request.log

```
2020-08-26T07:05:43.041Z|1765ac2ce37a6ffc|34.232.119.183|gradle-build|PUT|/gradle-dev-local/app/app-front/1.0.1.418_dev/app-front-1.0.1.418_dev.war;build.timestamp=1598425011065;build.name=app;build.number=1598425011337|404|0|0|9|ArtifactoryBuildClient/2.18.0
```

```
2020-08-26T07:05:44.014Z|e62cf9a7063d3fff|34.232.119.183|gradle-build|PUT|/gradle-dev-local/com/customer/app/app-core/1.0.1.418_dev/app-core-1.0.1.418_dev.pom;build.timestamp=1598425011065;build.name=app;build.number=1598425011337|404|4474|0|184|ArtifactoryBuildClient/2.18.0
```

Does anyone has an idea what could be the reason and what could be checked on top?

We deploying via Artifactory plugin & gradle. (https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars/build-info-extractor-gradle#release)

We use fix version but I also updated the plugin to 4.17.1 (before we used 4.9.8)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like more of an internal issue than something with your client.
It sounds like you may be using some sort of cloud storage, which in turn is using eventual storage. I can imagine a situation like this arising from using a mounted eventual directory over a sharded one in an HA setup.

I'd recommend to see whether that file exists in the filestore still or if it has weird permissions that couldn't be removed. If it is indeed a mounted eventual it'd be worth checking too if the request to upload that artifact came in multiple times; perhaps it was a collision of some sort.

Along those lines, since it's a 404 (not found) and it couldn't delete that file; I'm wondering whether it just couldn't write it to *_add* in the first place.

To summarize it could be one of two in my opinion with the information so far:

- You are using a mounted eventual directory, which may be causing issues
- The permissions on the filestore are not correct, affecting the filestore operations

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! 

So we using the Artifactory cloud service and deploying in a local repository.
The user for the deployment has write access but I think on the cloud service you are not able to configure file permissions. The Bitbucket (Cloud) pipeline run in a docker image which is a ubuntu 18.04. 

In the mean time I have tested gradle deployment locally and I am able to push data to Artifactory.

So it seems there is an issue on bitbucket / pipeline side or  the docker image.
But neither the pipeline or image were changed recently.

Comment: I see, that makes sense; I'm wondering whether the streaming begins and is cut short; or if the call sends the request with empty body due to the file permission issue. Do you have request log entries from Artifactory that could show us the request size?
Otherwise I'm thinking only some files are allowed and some not, and as it is docker it may be failing the whole request after partial upload, triggering a cleanup and the warnings we see

Comment: I get two errors for two artifacts in request logs (I have added above) during pushing to artifactory.

Comment: it seems like following issue - if gradle runs and provided sha1 checksums to artifactory all existing artifacts are fine. if there is a new artifact it returns a 404 (not found). This should not break the build but it does. This comes by artifactory gradle plugin which use following hardcoded value:  

private static final int CHECKSUM_DEPLOY_MIN_FILE_SIZE = 10240; // Try checksum deploy of files greater than 10KB
This triggers X-Checksum-Deploy.

It seems that Artifactory changed behavior recently which cause this Issue.

Comment: "Description: Deploy an artifact to the specified destination by checking if the artifact content already exists in Artifactory.
If Artifactory already contains a user readable artifact with the same checksum the artifact content is copied over to the new location and returns a response without requiring content transfer.
Otherwise, a 404 error is returned to indicate that content upload is expected in order to deploy the artifact."

It seems there was something changed and the 404 breaks the pipeline.